# Identity Manager ArcGIS API for Android

Tags: android, arcgis-android, authentication

im currently building some android application with arcgis, but my client using Identity Manager for auth user on the portal,

i have tried using oauth2 Rest with token in my local development and going well, but when using client portal it's not working,

is there Identity Manager ArcGIS API for Android sample or some kind of documentation on the grid that i can read ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not an IdentityManager class/API in ArcGIS Android API with v10.2.x.  It currently supports user credentials, token based or HTTP authentication.  You can implement self-signed certificates as well, more information can be found in this [developers guide doc](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/working-with-secure-arcgis-services.htm).  Moving forward with Quartz there will be support for a credential cache and challenge handler, but currently you would have to implement that yourself.  Quartz is currently in [beta](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/beta/) and initial support for credential cache and challenge handler is expected in the beta-2 release.

Comment: yeah, i have done, that, but my client apps using OAM and IDM from oracle,at least i have to explore more :)